# Rails 4 Set Value of the logged in User by default before create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following models

```
members (id, name, company_id..)
companies (id, name, ...)
campaigns (id, company_id, ...)
```

When creating a Campaign i have the following

```
def create
    @campaign = Campaign.new(campaign_params)
    if @campaign.save
      redirect_to campaigns_path(@campaign)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

i have a helper method from the `AppController` called `current_company` whose id i want to set to `@campagin.company_id`

which is the best way to set the default logged in users `company.id` to every campaign created?

can i traverse through `current_company` and build a query like this?

```
@campaign = current_company.campaign.new(campaign_params)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `before_create` callback in model for your goal:

```
before_create :set_default

private

def set_default
  self.campaign_id ||= your_default_id
end
```

Or you can do same thing it in your controller directly:

```
def create
  campaign_params[:company_id] ||= default_company_id
  @campaign = Campaign.new(campaign_params)
  if @campaign.save
    redirect_to campaigns_path(@campaign)
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: does it make sense to do something like this while creating the object `@campaign = current_company.campaign.new(campaign_params)` since its a method from the application controller and not available in the models